# Is it possible to use multiple, comma deliminated strings, as a TypeScript type?

Tags: string, typescript, types, literals

I know its possible to create `Type LayoutType = "Left" | "Right" | "Top" | "Bottom" | "VCenter"`, is it possible to create a type that would result in "Left,VCenter"? Or am I looking at creating a string literal for ***every*** possible type?

Answer (score 0):

For this use case you could add a type `Type LayoutTypes = LayoutType[];` which is an array which can accept multiple values that you specified for type LayoutType.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Typescript at the moment.

You can try use [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple)

```js
type LayoutType = ["Left" | "Right" | "HCenter", "Top" | "Bottom" | "VCenter"];

const layout: LayoutType = ["Left", "VCenter"]
```

Check it in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghiA9gV2AFXNAvFA2gIhggDNh8oAfKfAJQEsBzACzMuoAkBhCAO2AgBO+ADTU0iMOSr4AQomDBEAWynUAatz6D8AXQDcAWABQxgMaIeAZ2BQANghTAAXLAeoMkKDgJFSI9Zr8QvpAA)